# If I get an HDMI switch that supports 4k, can it 'downsample' to my monitor's native resolution?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, resolution

My screen is 144hz 1920x1080. I (stupidly) bought a switch that only supports 1080p (to get my Nintendo Switch, PS4, and PC all on the same screen with one cord).

So when I boot my PC and put its video through the switch, the only available resolution to pick is a very low 1024x786 (and one lower).

When I go directly from the PC, I get all options including `1920x1080 (preferred)`.

So my question is, if I buy a switch that purports to pass through 4K signals, is that 'enough' and does HDMI work in such a way that it will sufficiently downgrade/sample my signal to my monitor's native resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switches are passive units, generally.  If the switch supports 4k, that simply means the proper signaling will go through.  It will not affect a 2k signal, as it is simply passing it through to the monitor.